# CakePHP remove empty relations

Tags: cakephp, has-many

I have relation Holiday hasMany Place (Place belongsTo Holiday).

I prepare some form in Holiday view:

```
echo $this->Form->input('name');
echo $this->Form->input('Place.0.name');
echo $this->Form->input('Place.1.name');
echo $this->Form->input('Place.2.name');
```

Now, when I add Holiday with 2 places, I can't save because the one is empty.
How remove empty record in model?

Comment: Can you post what you've done so far?

Comment: can you post your add controller?

Comment: I'm not sure what your database requirements are, but you could always allow NULL for that field. Regardless, I'd suggest posting your action for this view.

Comment: @never: controller action add is simple, just `save()`

Comment: @user1104854: I can't allow null, this record don't be saved

Comment: @kicaj I meant in your database, allow the field in that table to be NULL. Right now if it's not saving, it's probably set to NOT NULL. Either that or I'm misunderstanding your problem. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through them, if it's empty, unset it.

```
foreach ($data['Place'] as $key => $place) {
    if (empty($place['name'])) {
        unset($data['Place'][$key]);
    }
}
```

Not sure about the paths, just update them accordingly to what your post data looks like.

Comment: I try this, I replace `$data` to `$this->data` but the results is the same - not deleted:/

Comment: Add to your question what your post data looks like and the current code you have.